# How to set a dependency property of a static resource?

Tags: wpf, xaml, staticresource

I would like to add a reference to my model in my view model using XAML. I have defined my model and my view model as resources, and I would like to bind the dependency property Model of the resource myViewModel to the resource myModel.

How do I do this using XAML?

Below is my attempt:

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ViewModel x:Key="myViewModel" />
    <local:Model x:Key="myModel" />
</Window.Resources>

<myViewModel Model="{StaticResource myModel}">
```

Comment: Does your VM have a named property of type `Model`?  But more importantly, what do you hope to achieve by doing a binding to a static resource? Does `Model` adhere to `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: @ΩmegaMan, Yes, my view model has a dependency property of type `Model`, which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

What I primarily hope to achieve is to create a view model object and a model object, and give the view model a reference to the model only using XAML.

A nice side effect is that if it turns out that there will be many proxy properties in the view model only mirroring properties in the model, I can allow the view to access those properties directly in the model, since it implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine:

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <local:Model x:Key="myModel" />
    <local:ViewModel x:Key="myViewModel" Model="{StaticResource myModel}" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Assuming, of course, the model data structures are declared appropriately (you didn't provide that context).